# What is the '._' convention in flutter/dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the following code in a flutter tutorial that discusses global state:

```
  static GlobalState instance = new GlobalState._();
  GlobalState._();
```

What exactly is the ._ doing? Is this technically just a blank method?

Comment: Curious: what tutorial is it? Singletons in flutter is an horrible idea

Comment: Ah didn't know it was a duplicate and it's a udemy one by Bryain Crains I believe called Flutter - Intermediate

Answer (score 5):

It's a private constructor. This pattern is used to prevent clients from instantiating or subclassing `GlobalState`, so the only available instance of `GlobalState` in the program is `instance`.